# Converting JSON data to VB.NET multidimensional array

Tags: asp.net, json, type-conversion, vb.net-2010

I have a multidimensional array converted to JSON data in this format.

```
"[[null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,1,1,null],[null,null,null,null,1,1],[null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null]]"
```

I am trying to conver this multidimensional array of strings/integers to equivalent form using JavascriptSerializer like this

```
 Dim retValue As List(Of String)
 Dim deserializer As System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()

retValue deserializer.Deserialize(Of List(Of String))(o.value)
```

Its throwing an exception: `Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array.`

I tried the same casting it to Integers
, but the same exception occured.

How can I perform the conversion using  .NET 3.5.

I dont want to use JSON.NET dll's , if System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer can do the job.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [null,null,null,1,1,null] -> 1 is not a string,should be [null,null,null,"1","1",null]

Comment: @Myra ok but I tried the conversions in Integer also , but the result was same, exception message just changed to Integer not supported. Thanks

Comment: Have you considered the DataContractJsonSerialiser (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)?  I would also be tempted to specifically apply a DataContract to the object (rather than a list of Strings) for serialising back and forth...

Comment: @SeanCocteau you mean to say ,I should create Data Contract class    and convert to that class object for doing this? That will be a lot of unwanted work ,right?  I just want my two dimensional array [By the converted format, I suppose it's jagged array] to equivalent VB.NET

Comment: Sorry I assumed you were dealing with specific object - hence the data contracts. Anyhoo - answer provided below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried two ways in achieving the solution:-

As per "SeanCocteau's comments:-

```
 Dim o As Object = JSONField
 Dim castObj() As Object = Nothing
 Dim ser As New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(System.Object))

 Using ms As New MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(o.Value().ToString))
   castObj = ser.ReadObject(ms)
 End Using

 Dim convObject As ArrayList = New ArrayList(castObj)
```

In this format, I was able to get the arrayList and then take each internal arrayList by iterating and casting appropriately

Second solution I tried:-

```
    Dim o As Object =  JSONField
    Dim obj() As Object = (New JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize(Of Object)(o.Value.ToString())
    Dim convObject As ArrayList = New ArrayList(obj)
```

In this format also , I was able to get the arrayList and then take each internal arrayList by iterating and casting appropriately

Thanks SeanCocteau for giving the tip to Convert it to Object first :)

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy JSONField contains a json style object [[a,b,c,d,e,f],[g,h,i,j,k,l]]

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to convert that Json into a one dimensional List of Strings when in fact it is a Jagged Array of Strings.  With Generics I don't believe you can smartly nest other strongly typed objects (although I welcome corrections to this) and you cannot easily convert them across (unless you had a rigid structure in which case a POCO with DataContracts would be the way forward).

My approach would be to serialise into an Object, where Strings, Integers and Arrays can co-exist happily; they simply need boxing out as appropriate.  Not ideal I admit.  I haven't tried the JavaScriptSerializer but have tested and confirmed the following works using DataContractJsonSerialiser...

```
string json = "[[null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,1,1,null],[null,null,null,null,1,1],[null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null]]";
            object castObj = null;
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer( typeof( System.Object ));

            // Create dummy stream to read into
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream( System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( json ) ) ){
                castObj = ser.ReadObject(ms);
            }
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks it helped. I then converted the Object to ArrayList and then taking each ArrayList from inside the ArrayList using indexes. I am looking for a crisp one. The catch is I know the type of Object I am getting back at the server.

Comment: Tbh - If you know the kind of object you are getting back, why not utilise a DTO (Data Transfer Object) to serialise to and deserialise from?  This would certainly save you the boxing hassle...

Comment: they are actually integers.[ A matrix representation containing either 0/1 in columns]. I was hoping to directly deserialise and type cast using Deserialize .But then I followed your suggestions